# Panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0. Program failed to complete

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, auction-house

I encountered an error while working on the Metaplex auction house. The situation was as follows: I listed an NFT, received three bids, and initially, I rejected one of them successfully, refunding the amount to the bidder's wallet. However, when I attempted to accept one of the remaining two bids, the Phantom wallet's confirmation popup appeared, but it displayed an error message stating, **"program failed to complete."** Despite this error message, I proceeded with the confirmation, and the transaction went through successfully. The bidder whose bid I accepted received the NFT, and the other bidder received their balance back. The issue appears to be related to the error message displayed in the terminal

> `UnknownProgramError: The program [AuctionHouseProgram] at address [hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.
> .
> Program Logs:
> | Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk invoke [1]
> | Program log: Instruction: Cancel
> | Program log: panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', src/cancel/mod.rs:244:19
> | Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk consumed 19540 of 400000 compute units
> | Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk failed: SBF program panicked